# How to manage routers with Redux React Native Router Flux

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to manage my routers with redux, i have "simple" scenes and scenes tabs, but the tabs need to appear according API.

I tried like this

router.js

```
createScenes = () => {
        Actions.create(
            <Scene tabs tabBarPosition="bottom" icon={TabIcon} showLabel={true} tabBarStyle={styles.Tabbar} hideNavBar activeTintColor="#3498db">
                { 
                    // this.props.user.permissions.length > 0 && (
                    //     <Scene key="Jornada" component={Jornada} title="Jornada" hideNavBar />
                    // )
                }
                <Scene key="Search" component={Search} title="Procurar" hideNavBar />
                <Scene key="Tracking" component={Tracking} title="Informar" hideNavBar />
                <Scene key="Profile" component={Profile} title="Profile" hideNavBar />
            </Scene>
        )
    }



    render(){
        return(
            <Root>
                <Router>
                    <Stack key="root">
                        <Scene key="Login" component={Login} title="Login" hideNavBar initial />
                        <Scene key="Senha" component={Senha} title="Senha" hideNavBar />
                        <Scene key="Cadastro" component={Cadastro} title="Cadastro" hideNavBar />

                        <Scene key="Choose" component={Choose} title="Choose" hideNavBar />

                        { this.createScenes() }

                        <Scene key="Item" component={Item} title="Item" hideNavBar  />

                        <Scene key="Baixar" component={Baixar} title="Baixar" hideNavBar />
                        <Scene key="Informar" component={Informar} title="Informar" hideNavBar />

                        <Scene key="Coleta" component={Coleta} title="Coleta" hideNavBar />
                    </Stack>
                </Router>
            </Root>
        )
    }
}
```

the idea is that I have routes (without tabbar) and that my user log in, depending on their level of user, I have some tabs and some not